# ANDROID passing variables between static void AND void method

Tags: android

I have two methods in the same class ..

```
public static void first_method (float x)
{
    float xx = x;
}


public void second_method (TextView tv)
{

 String xs = Float.toString(xx);
 tv.setText(xs);

}
```

How I can pass the variable xx from first method to second method ?

THANKS

Comment: The best way for solving your problem is [this](http://www.amazon.com/Java-For-Dummies-Computer-Tech/dp/1118407806)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following thing: 1.set the variable, you want pass between the methods, as public out of both methods (but IN the activity class in which you are). 2.Assign it a new value in the methods you write and use it as you like

Use the following code:

```
public float xx;

public static void first_method (float x){
    xx = x;
}


public void second_method (TextView tv){

    String xs = Float.toString(xx);
    tv.setText(xs);
}
```

Comment: non static field 'xx' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: make it static -> `public static float xx;`

Comment: 'first_method(float)' in 'com.android.hamdi.Class2' clashes with 'first_method(float)' in 'com.android.hamdi.Class1' : attempting to use incompatible return type

Comment: but your return type is void. Isn't it?

Comment: Try to remove the `static` from the method signature

Comment: Class 1 :

'code' case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
    Class2.affichX(eventX);

Comment: I can't understand you... What do you mean with this line, that you wrote above

Answer (score 0):

you cant pass variables through methods. It must be a field outside both methods in order to be used by both. Since first method is static, cariable should be also static

```
Class MyCoolClass {
 static float xx;

 public static void first_method (float x)
 {
     xx = x;
 }


 public void second_method (TextView tv)
 {

   String xs = Float.toString(xx);
   tv.setText(xs);

 }
}
```

Comment: non static field 'xx' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: you're right, "xx" must be static. I edited my answer

Comment: xx in the second method it's always null

Comment: then something is wrong with your first method, or you're not calling the first method

Answer (score 0):

*Be careful!*  Remember: a **static** method belongs "to *the class itself*," not to any particular instance of it.  A static method does not have an "implicit `this`" that it can refer to.  Static methods are often used to build, for instance, "factories," using private (but also, static) variables which they conceal.

I suggest that you re-consider your design.  Construct an instance of the class, and let *it* simply call the methods that it needs to use ... which methods now have no particular *reason* to be `static`.